# gRPC Kotlin Codegen Plugin for Protobuf Compiler it generates only one class

Tags: java, kotlin, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to generate classes for my grpc client in kotlin but it only generates one class I'm following this tutorial [link](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-kotlin/tree/master/compiler#manual-protoc-usage) I already have protoc installed on my ubuntu I will post how is the protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin.sh and my proto. If anyone knows where I'm going wrong, I'd appreciate it.

my protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"
java -jar $DIR/protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin-1.3.0-jdk8.jar $@
```

I am using **protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin-1.3.0-jdk8.jar** plugin

My java version is 17 but I tested it with version 8 and it didn't work either

My HelloService.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package com.example.grpc;
option java_multiple_files = true;
//import "google/api/annotations.proto";

message HelloRequest {
    string firstName = 1;
    string lastName = 2;
}

message HelloResponse {
    string greeting =1;
}

service HelloService {
    rpc hello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloResponse) {}
//    rpc hello(HelloRequest) returns (HelloResponse){
//        option (google.api.http) = {
//            post: "/demo/item"
//            body: "*"
//        };
//    }
}
```

protoc command:

```
protoc --kotlin_out=. --java_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-kotlin=protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin.sh --proto_path=. HelloService.proto
```

Java classes are normally generated but Create only one kotlin service

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You also need to run protoc with the [java plugin](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/grpc/protoc-gen-grpc-java/1.56.0/) to generate the Java classes.  Something like:

```
# generate java message stubs
protoc --java_out=. --proto_path=. HelloService.proto

# generate kotlin message stubs
protoc --kotlin_out=. --proto_path=. HelloService.proto

# generate java service stubs
protoc --grpc-java_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc-java=protoc-gen-grpc-java.exe --proto_path=. HelloService.proto

# generate kotlin service stubs
protoc --grpc-kotlin_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin=protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin.sh --proto_path=. HelloService.proto
```

Comment: only have .exe is this the same? tonly have .exe is this the same? my system is linux ubuntu 64 bits hank for feedback.

Comment: Oh, yeah for protoc-gen-grpc-java you should be able to use their `exe` which I think is just an executable jar.

Comment: the examples generates all classes but does not generate a HelloServiceGrpc class

Comment: Yes, you have to run protoc for messages and for services. I've updated the answer with maybe the right way to do the 4 necessary runs but can't remember if the plugin is needed for the messages.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not correctly compiling or generating the Java proto and gRPC classes that are necessary to use gRPC for Kotlin.  It is normal and expected that the code you've shown should only generates one Kotlin file.

(If you're looking for Kotlin DSLs for your proto messages etc., that's a separate feature of protobuf, not gRPC.)

Comment: I saw that it is normal to generate some java classes but it failed to generate the HelloServiceGrpc class thank for feedback.